# Removing private properties of object

Tags: php, oop

Tried and searched this but never seemed to find it here in SO
tried using `unset($this->property_name)` but it still shows up when I use a `print_r($object_name)`, is it impossible to remove a private property of an object?

here's a sample code

```
class my_obj
{
    private $a, $b, $c, $d;
    public function __construct($data = null)
    {
        if($data)
        {
            foreach($data as $key)
            {
                if(property_exists($this,$key))
                {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

implementation:

```
$test = new my_obj(array('a'=>a, 'c'=>'c'));
echo '<pre>',print_r($test,TRUE),'</pre>';
```

the output would be something like this

```
my_obj Object
(
    [a:my_obje:private] => a
    [b:my_obje:private] => 
    [c:my_obje:private] => c
    [d:my_obje:private] => 
)
```

now i want those properties that are not set to be entirely removed
again i tried unset and it doesnt seem to work

thanks for all that cared to answer this

Comment: Stereotypical question. Why would you want to do such a thing? There has to be a better solution.

Comment: do you have to predefine them?

Comment: my_obj will be a template for its implementation, the target object implementations would contain specific properties not the whole, so if the properties would be high then we would be carrying the whole set of properties instead of a subset of those that are set using the contructor, i would be implementing it something like `$a = new my_obj(array('a'=>'a'))` ; `$ab = new my_obj(array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b'))` and something like this `$abd = new my_obj(array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b','d'=>'d'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that there's got be a better way to do you whatever it is that you need this for (you should explain the problem you need to solve in another question so that we can help you find a better solution), you can indeed remove private property as long as you do it in a context where you can access them.

```
class test
{
  private $prop = 'test';

  public function deleteProp()
  {
    unset($this->prop);
  }
}

$var = new test();
var_dump($var); // object(test)#1 (1) {["prop":"test":private] => string(4) "test"}
$var->deleteProp();
var_dump($var); // object(test)#1 (0) { }
```

Comment: $var->deleteProp() of course and not $var->delete(), cannot edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind creating a new object, you could use PHP's built-in get_object_vars():

```
$public_properties = get_object_vars($object); // get only the public properties of the object
$public_properties = (object)$public_properties; // turn array back into object
```

For more information, see http://php.net/manual/function.get-object-vars.php

edited: corrected typo

Comment: All the properties in this question is private, so this solution is not going to work.

Comment: I read the question such as the thread opener is trying to remove private properties from the object. If all properties are private, the resulting object should be empty (haven't tested it, though).

The above mentioned method won't keep the objects methods, though. If that is of concern, you'd have to come up with some additional code.