# How can I remove a private property from an array of object?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, object, properties

```
$array = $this->em->getRepository($entity)->filter($id);
```

With doctrine I am creating an array:

```
array:24 [▼
  0 => Members^ {#543 ▼
    -id: 1
    -username: "lio"
    -email: "info@somepage.com"
    -isActive: true
    -name: "Lio"
    -projects: PersistentCollection^ {#590 ▶}
    -pages: PersistentCollection^ {#615 ▶}
  }
  1 => Members^ {#135029 ▶}
  2 => Members^ {#125937 ▶}
  3 => Members^ {#1807 ▶}
  4 => Members^ {#135075 ▶}
  5 => Members^ {#135086 ▶}
```

From this array I try to remove the object projects:

```
 foreach ($array as $value) {
      dump($value->projects);
    }
```

I get the error message that the object is private.

I found this post, but there it is written, that I need to write a function inside the class.

[Removing private properties of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039045/removing-private-properties-of-object)

My question is, is it possible to remove it outside the class? Because when I remove it inside the class it is always removed and I want to remove it only in a specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array of `Member` object. A private attribute of an object can only be access through its method. You need to find the file that declares the class `Member`. Then add a public class method to do the [unset](https://www.php.net/unset). For example,

```php
class Member {

  // ...
  public function unsetProjects()
  {
    unset($this->projects);
  }

}
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```php
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $value->unsetProjects();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use it now like this `foreach ($array as $value) {unsetProjects($value);}` but I get an error message `Attempted to call function "unsetProjects" from namespace "App\Service".`

Comment: Sorry. I assumed you have some understanding to object-oriented programming. Updated my answer to show you how to call the method of the object instance.

Answer (score -1):

You should use getters and setters

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
      dump($value->getProjects());
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried `unset($value->getProjects());` but I get the error: `Compile Error: Can't use method return value in write context`